# .Focus() do not focus label control in deployment site, only can focus it in development site

Tags: asp.net

.Focus() do not focus label control in deployment site, only can focus it in development site

this page is in aspx's iframe

i have already put this focus at the beginning and end of onclick event
however got this problem.

what should i do?

the goal is to go back at the top of the page when having validation error

after this focus in page_load also failed

then i try defaultfocus in page_load, also failed

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
Page.Form.DefaultFocus = candRegFormMessage.ClientID;
```

chrome, firefox and internet explorer can focus it after press submit in development site.
after upload to production site, got this problem

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">

    <asp:Panel ID="candRegFormPanel" runat="server" Visible="false">
        <asp:Label ID="candRegFormMessage" runat="server" ForeColor="Red"></asp:Label>
    </asp:Panel>

public void candRegSubmission(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string errorMessage = "";
        string candEntityID = "";
        candRegFormMessage.Focus();

        if (IsValid)
        {

    ....very long
}
 candRegFormMessage.Focus();
}
```

finally i try MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="false" in masterfile
also failed

Comment: actually i have no idea where is wrong, i only cooperate with a web designer who in another company. i do not know who did what in production site

Comment: err no, focus is part of the DOM, and only allowed on elements that meet specific criteria.

Comment: Can we see some example code? what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('#candRegSubmit').click(
       function () {
           getParent().window.scrollTo(0, 0);
       });
```

Comment: this is also failed, where should i check?